# Hide raw .svelte files from developer tools in production

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

currently when i open developer tools in a browser i can see my raw svelte components i'd like to hide this information and send only the uglified code.

this is what i get when open developer tools. I am building a `single page application.`

this is my [rollup.config.js](https://pastebin.com/KzQx7qUF)

this are the scripts I use to run the project/rollup. found in `package.json`

```json
 "scripts": {
      "build": "rollup -c",
      "dev": "rollup -c -w",
      "start": "sirv public --host 0.0.0.0 --port 2222 --single"
}
```

for production i run `npm run build`

[image]

I have set `sourcemap: false`, in `rollup.config.js`, the source file has disappeared from the `/public/build` folder, however browsers still show the components

Comment: This has nothing to do with svelte specifically. Which bundler are you using and how is it configured? Enable production build mode for your bundler.

Comment: I am using rollup, and i could not really find which configuration to edit to remove this behavior, i have attached a pastebin link to the code, Thank you

Comment: How are you executing rollup?

Comment: i call 'npm run build', this project is cloned from the svelte template found in the official website, i have added all the scripts to the description that are found in package.json

Comment: sometimes caused by server/browser cache, did you tried using browser guest mode? or clean previous build after change `rollup config`? or maybe try using `esm` in output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** use the latest plugins for rollup while building then in `rollup.config.js` set `output.sourcemap: false`

As you can see in the photo attached in the question the .svelte files are colored in blue, this indicates that Opera/DevTools treats them as CSS files.

Also the files are inside `/build`

if you set `output.sourcemap: true` the `.svelte` files will show up in a new `/src` folder in the devtools which will be treated as javascript files in the devtools colored yellow. You will also have the source files in `/src` and `/build`

this issue is due that `rollup-plugin-svelte` in version `6.0.0` used to compile a sourcemap of the CSS of the project. this sourcemap loaded the whole raw `.svelte` file instead of just the css. this will lead to a CSS file in the dev tools that includes your whole svelte code of each component (colored blue in devtools as my issue)

in `rollup-plugin-svelte` version `7.0.0` this issue is resolved as `rollup-plugin-svelte` no longer handles the generation of the css and a new plugin is being used `rollup-plugin-css-only` (v3.1.0 on the moment of writing)

**Solution:** use the latest plugins (specifically `rollup-plugin-svelte`)

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [default svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) it is configured to include the source maps, in your `rollup.config.js` change the output object to

```json
output: {
   sourcemap: !production
}
```

this will enable sourcemaps while developing, but not when you are in production

Comment: hi, i have set sourcemap to false and still seeing the files

Comment: this should work, they might be cached on your server. try changing something very obvious and check if the files you see include this change, if not they are somehow old versions

Comment: I am sorry, but the modifications are still being updated in the dev tools .svelte files

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers didn't work for me. No matter what I tried, the svelte source files were still showing up in the CSS bundle source map. I gave up after spending a long time trying to configure rollup, and just wrote an inlined plugin to delete the source map files:

```js
function rmSourceMaps() {
  return {
    name: 'rmSourceMaps',
    generateBundle() {
      fs.rmSync('public/build/bundle.css.map', { force: true });
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```js
{
  plugins: [
    production && rmSourceMaps()
  ]
}
```

Comment: just a note, `fs.rmSync` requires node v14